# Web scraper for restaurant ratings

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm new to using type hinting in Python. I've used it for a small scraper I had to build (see code below), everything works fine and mypy gives no errors. However I'm sure there are better ways to write this (avoiding the repetition between the `Ratings` and `ScrapedData` tuples, better way to handle the `Literal` in function signature). Any feedback is greatly appreciated, even on other aspects of the code.

I'm using Python 3.7 so I don't think I can use `TypedDict`.

```
import os
import requests
import lxml.html
import pandas as pd
from lxml.html import HtmlElement
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from enum import Enum
from typing import List, Optional, NamedTuple
from typing_extensions import Literal
from multiprocessing import Pool

HEADER = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

TITLE_XPATH = '//div[@class="review-title"]'
REVIEW_XPATH = '//section[@class="review-container"]'
SENTIMENT_XPATH = '//div[@class="left-header"]'

RATING_XPATH = '//section[@itemprop="reviewrating"]'
SUBJECT_XPATH = './/div[@class="subject"]'
STAR_XPATH = './/span[@class="or-sprite-inline-block common_yellowstar_desktop"]'

POSITIVE_XPATH = './/div[contains(@class, "smiley_smile")]'
NEUTRAL_XPATH = './/div[contains(@class, "smiley_ok")]'
NEGATIVE_XPATH = './/div[contains(@class, "smiley_cry")]'


class Evaluation(Enum):
    POSITIVE: int = 1
    NEUTRAL: int = 0
    NEGATIVE: int = -1
    NONE: None = None


class Ratings(NamedTuple):

    taste: Optional[int] = None
    environment: Optional[int] = None
    service: Optional[int] = None
    hygiene: Optional[int] = None
    value: Optional[int] = None


class ScrapedData(NamedTuple):
    url: str
    title: Optional[str] = None
    review: Optional[str] = None
    sentiment: Literal[
        Evaluation.POSITIVE, Evaluation.NEUTRAL, Evaluation.NEGATIVE, Evaluation.NONE
    ] = Evaluation.NONE
    taste: Optional[int] = None
    environment: Optional[int] = None
    service: Optional[int] = None
    hygiene: Optional[int] = None
    value: Optional[int] = None


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, url_file: str) -> None:

        if not os.path.exists(url_file):
            raise OSError("File Not Found: %s" % url_file)

        with open(url_file, "r") as fp:
            self.urls = [_.strip() for _ in fp.readlines()]

        self.data: list = []

    @staticmethod
    def __requests_retry_session(
        retries: int = 3,
        backoff_factor: float = 0.3,
        status_forcelist: tuple = (500, 502, 504),
        session: Session = None,
    ) -> Session:
        """
        Handles retries for request HTTP requests params are similar to those
        for requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry.Retry
        https://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-practice-with-retries-with-requests
        """
        session = session or requests.Session()
        retry = Retry(
            total=retries,
            read=retries,
            connect=retries,
            backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
            status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
        )
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        session.mount("http://", adapter)
        session.mount("https://", adapter)
        return session

    @staticmethod
    def __safe_extract_text(elements: List[HtmlElement]) -> Optional[str]:
        """
        Returns the text content of the first element extracted from Xpath or None if none has been found
        :param elements:
        The result of a call to .xpath on the tree
        :return: the string extracted or None if there are no elements
        """
        if len(elements) > 0:
            return elements[0].text_content()
        else:
            return None

    @staticmethod
    def __extract_sentiment(
        elements: List[HtmlElement]
    ) -> Literal[
        Evaluation.POSITIVE, Evaluation.NEUTRAL, Evaluation.NEGATIVE, Evaluation.NONE
    ]:

        if len(elements) < 1:
            return Evaluation.NONE
        element = elements[0]
        if len(element.xpath(POSITIVE_XPATH)) > 0:
            return Evaluation.POSITIVE
        elif len(element.xpath(NEUTRAL_XPATH)) > 0:
            return Evaluation.NEUTRAL
        elif len(element.xpath(NEGATIVE_XPATH)) > 0:
            return Evaluation.NEGATIVE
        return Evaluation.NONE

    @staticmethod
    def __extract_ratings(elements) -> Ratings:

        if len(elements) < 1:
            return Ratings()

        element = elements[0]
        rating_subjects = element.xpath(SUBJECT_XPATH)
        if len(rating_subjects) != 5:
            return Ratings()

        extracted_ratings = Ratings(
            *[len(_.xpath(STAR_XPATH)) for _ in rating_subjects]
        )

        return extracted_ratings

    def scrape_page(self, url: str) -> ScrapedData:

        print("Scraping : %s" % url)
        r = self.__requests_retry_session().get(url, headers=HEADER, timeout=10)
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)

        # Extract title
        title = self.__safe_extract_text(tree.xpath(TITLE_XPATH))

        # Extract review
        review = self.__safe_extract_text(tree.xpath(REVIEW_XPATH))

        # Extract overall sentiment
        sentiment = self.__extract_sentiment(tree.xpath(SENTIMENT_XPATH))

        # Extract specific grades
        ratings = self.__extract_ratings(tree.xpath(RATING_XPATH))

        return ScrapedData(
            url, title, review, sentiment.value, *ratings._asdict().values()
        )

    def scrape(self) -> None:
        p = Pool(5)
        self.data = p.map(self.scrape_page, self.urls)
        p.terminate()
        p.join()

    def save(self, output_file: str = "content.csv"):
        data = pd.DataFrame(self.data)
        data.to_csv(output_file, index=None)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Scraper("reviewsurl.csv")
    s.scrape()
    s.save()
```

Comment: Just a quick comment: in Python 3.7 `TypedDict` is available in `typing_extensions` even though it didn't land in `typing` until 3.8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Optional

I find it less useful to include `None` in an enum like `Evaluation`, and more useful to write `Optional[Evaluation]` where appropriate. It's useful to be able to choose whether you have a value that cannot be `None` at a certain point, or otherwise, based on context.

In other words, this:

```
sentiment: Literal[
        Evaluation.POSITIVE, Evaluation.NEUTRAL, Evaluation.NEGATIVE, Evaluation.NONE
    ] = Evaluation.NONE
```

can just be

```
sentiment: Optional[Evaluation] = None
```

The same goes for the return value of `__extract_sentiment`.

### File existence

I find this:

```
    if not os.path.exists(url_file):
        raise OSError("File Not Found: %s" % url_file)
```

to be redundant. `open` will do that for you.

### Lists

Since you're learning about type hinting: what is this a list *of*?

```
self.data: list = []
```

Similarly, this:

```
status_forcelist: tuple = (500, 502, 504)
```

is probably

```
status_forcelist: Tuple[int, ...] = (500, 502, 504)
```

### Inner lists

```
    extracted_ratings = Ratings(
        *[len(_.xpath(STAR_XPATH)) for _ in rating_subjects]
    )
```

should be

```
    extracted_ratings = Ratings(
        *(len(_.xpath(STAR_XPATH)) for _ in rating_subjects)
    )
```

In other words, unpack a generator, not a materialized list. Also, never call a variable `_` if you actually use it.